# What is the average helpful/declined flag rate?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Having just surpassed 500 helpful flags (and got a wonderful gold badge!) I'm wondering how my accuracy in flagging is compared to the average user.

**Where can I look for average percentages of declined to helpful flags for the various categories of flag?**

In case numbers can't be disclosed, here is my current flagging history to allow for comments such as 'high'/'low':

[image]

Comment: If I keep forgetting that incorrect answers shouldn't be flagged I'll catch you on moderator attention flags declined long before I get up to 400+ helpful (I have 4 declined out of 67)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer: I'm afraid you can't ;)

Flags is like votes, you can see your own, we can't.  You have access to the raw data, and can compile stats from it, but there's no handy page, not even for a Mod, that will do it.

Comment: Ah, that's a shame :(

Comment: Not even on a data export?

Comment: Doing some digging on Meta.SE—you can't get a user's flag history [even with a direct link](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/37797)? (previous link should 404 except ♦ and me?)

Comment: Mods can see that link, yes, but that per user, not per flag type.